# Is Jax-RS the right solution for communicating with web services?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jax-rs

I'm going to be beginning a project soon that will be written in Java and will communicate with a PHP based web service.  I initially thought with what I was reading that Jax-RS would be the right solution because I thought that my Java side would need to be a Web Service.  Since then I've learned it won't, but it'll have a lot of communicating to do with Java.  Is Jax-RS a good solution if I'm sending requests and receiving responses?  Is there another tool or just standard java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *consume* (RESTful) web services, then you could use a so-called client-API. Most JAX-RS implementations like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/) include one, e.g:

[Consuming RESTful Web Services With the Jersey Client API](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with)

Do note that this isn't yet part of the JAX-RS standard, but it soon will be:

- [JAX-RS 2.0 - Client API](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/spericas/archive/2011/10/14/jax-rs-20-client-api)
- [JAX-RS 2.0 Client API: Generic Interface](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/spericas/archive/2011/10/20/jax-rs-20-client-api-generic-interface)

Comment: I've found Jersey particularly easy to use. If your POJOs are annotated correctly it takes just a few lines to make the call and get the unmarshalled objects.

Comment: Besides those two frameworks I'd recommend CXF, it's easy to use and has great integration with spring and it's easy to deploy on servlet containers like tomcat or jetty

Answer (score 0):

Standard Java: [HttpUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

3rd Party: Apache [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [RestTester](http://www.rexsl.com/rexsl-test/apidocs/com/rexsl/test/RestTester.html) from [rexsl-test](http://www.rexsl.com/rexsl-test) client. It is a RESTful client with built-in assertion functionality. You make requests and run assertions on response using a simple [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).